# Minecraft unplayable - not using 100% GPU

Tags: graphics-card, java, gpu

I have a serious issue with Minecraft, it's unplayable.

My PC specs:

Storage/Drive     - SAMSUNG SSD 980 NVMe M.2 1TB
MainBoard         - Asus ROG Maximus XI Hero Gaming 1151 ATX Z390
Power Supply      - BeQuiet Dark Power Pro 11 850 Watt ATX Platinum
OS                - Windows 10 Pro 64Bit 21H1
CPU               - INTEL Core i7 8700k
GPU               - GeForce GTX 1080 Ti OC 11GB
Ram/Memory        - 2x16GB DDR4 3200MHz
Display/Monitor   - 2560x1440 165Hz Gsync

Minecraft graphic settings are all on max.
I have optifine installed for minecraft 1.16.5.
I'm using a shaderpack called SEUS renewed 2020.
In the minecraft launcher I choose to use javaw.exe instead of the pre-installed Java.
In the Nvidia control panel all graphic settings are on max.

I played Minecraft on windows 1909 with those exact settings written above,
I always had 70 up to 140 fps with optifine and with the seus shader.
Now I clean installed windows 21H1, again I am using the exact same settings as written above
but Minecraft performance is horrible.
I have 30 up to 70 fps.

I have tried reinstalling Minecraft and Java and my GPU driver many times also with different versions,
The result is the same: Minecraft performance is unplayable.

Normally when playing Minecraft my GPU was always running at its temp limit 84 C.
Now its chilling at 50 C up to 70 C, the GPU load is ONLY going from 40% up to 70%.
So basically Minecraft does not correctly use my GPU, it's not using its full potential.
I play various different games, Minecraft is the only game where my GPU is not being used correctly.

After many many hours trying to fix this by myself, I now have no clue what to do anymore.

Comment: Did you install 32 or 64-bit Java? How much RAM do you have allocated to Minecraft (using the Java launch options in the Minecraft launcher)?

Comment: I would try running it without this shader pack and use the provided Java.  Java is not preinstalled on Windows. Unclear what version of Java you ended up installing.

Comment: jre-8u301-windows-x64

Comment: the latest java version from oracle 64bit, i dont use the java that comes with minecraft i use the javaw.exe that i manually installed because i needed this to install optifine and it seems to be recommended. i will not play without the shaderpack. this is neither a good suggestions nor does it help, i want to fix minecraft performance issue not some people telling me to remove my shader.

Comment: i have 32gb ram i already tryed setting the ram to 4gb instead of 2 but that makes zero difference.

Comment: You only have to increase the amount of virtual ram that Java can use if and only if you get an Java error that indicates the JVM ran out of memory.  Shaders would use the VRAM (video ram) not your virtual ram